# Extract lines between specific start/end pattern from text file

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I want to extract the lines between specified start-pattern (inclusive) and end-pattern (exclusive).

My code below does extract some lines, but not the first line that matches the start-pattern.
In my desired target output I want also the first line that matches.

### Code Attempt

```py
import re
import xlswriter

linenum = 0
myline = []
pattern_start = re.compile(r"^vsi ipcbb")
pattern_stop = re.compile(r"^vsi ipcbb-ipran")
with open(r'readline.txt', 'rt') as myfile :
    for row in myfile :
      if pattern_start.search(row) != None :
        for line in myfile :
            linenum += 1
            if pattern_stop.search(line) != None:
                break
            myline.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('readline.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('VSI')
    for row_num,data in enumerate(myline):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num + 0, 0, data)
```

### Given Input as text file

```
!Last configuration was updated at 2021-04-22 05:52:21 UTC by 
!Last configuration was saved at 2021-04-22 19:00:49 UTC by 
!PdtPrivateInfo = System current forwarding-mode: compatible
!MKHash 0000000000000000
vsi ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H-00 static
 description *** M-ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H(via RAG_MBSPM01H&RAG_YBPNM01H) ***
 tnl-policy TE
 diffserv-mode pipe af1 green
#
vsi ipcbb-ipran-RSG_NKY2M-00 static
 description *** IPCBB-IPRAN VLAN61 Inherit(RAG_NKY2M01H-RAG_NKY2M02H) ***
 tnl-policy TE
 diffserv-mode pipe af1 green
#
```

### Actual Output (lines extracted)

```
 description *** M-ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H(via RAG_MBSPM01H&RAG_YBPNM01H) ***
 tnl-policy TE
 diffserv-mode pipe af1 green
#
```

### Wanted Output (lines extracted)

```
vsi ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H-00 static
 description *** M-ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H(via RAG_MBSPM01H&RAG_YBPNM01H) ***
 tnl-policy TE
 diffserv-mode pipe af1 green
#
```

Comment: Hello, please add sample input for your code, and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). please also include an example of the output you are trying to achieve. See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details

Comment: @ExtraFishness The code is reproducible now (imports added) and in-/output given by author, I refined the textual clarity slightly. Now it deserves upvotes. Dear saratoon J., I hope it covers all you asked for ️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a boolean mode-flag like `extract_on`, which signals if currently in between start and stop and should extract the line.
Also the line-matching can be done using `re.match` function, which either returns a match-object or `None`.

```py
import re

pattern_start = re.compile(r"^vsi ipcbb")
pattern_stop = re.compile(r"^vsi ipcbb-ipran")

i = 0
extract_on = False
extracts = []
with open(r'readline.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        i += 1  # line counting starts with 1
        if pattern_start.match(line):
            extract_on = True
        if pattern_stop.search(line):
            extract_on = False
        if extract_on:
            extracts.append((i, line.rstrip('\n')))

for line in extracts:
    print(line)
```

Given your input, it will ignore the first 4 lines, extract the middle 5, and again ignores the last 5.
So print-out of extracted lines including position-in-file is:

```
(5, 'vsi ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H-00 static')
(6, ' description *** M-ipcbb-RAC_YBPNM01H(via RAG_MBSPM01H&RAG_YBPNM01H) ***')
(7, ' tnl-policy TE')
(8, ' diffserv-mode pipe af1 green')
(9, '#')
```

Left out the XLS-writing, which is assumed to be working as expected.

Comment: I',m sorry  about input text have information above of them also like , I update of my input file on above.

Comment: Hi, hc_dev now my coding is working !!! ,thank you for your suggestion and help.